# How do I solve the recurrence relation $A_n=2A_{n-1}+3 | A_0=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I tried working it backwards and ended up with $2+3n$, which is incorrect, and when I work it forwards I et nowhere other than I found that each time in is increased, $A_n$ is increased by $2^{n+1}$. I am not sure how to solve it from there. Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

**EDIT: $A_0$ = 1, I'm sorry I typed the wrong number.**

Comment: Have you taken differential equations? The approach is similar here, except now you try the solution $A_n = r^n$ and solve. Or, unfold it carefully and show the result by induction.

Comment: We have not yet learned induction in my discrete mathematics class, and I am not allowed to use it yet.

Comment: It's one way of many. I anticipate in the next two weeks you should be shown induction. What good is a discrete math class without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint :"We have not yet learned induction in my discrete mathematics class, and I am not allowed to use it yet. "  so you can do this :
$$A_{n+1}=2A_{n}+3\\A_{n+1}=2(2A_{n-1}+3)+3=2^2A_{n-1}+6+3\\
A_{n+1}=2^2(2A_{n-2}+3)+9=2^3A_{n-2}+12+6+3\\
A_{n+1}=2^3(2A_{n-3}+3)+12+9\\=2^4A_{n-3}+24+12+6+3\\...$$so $$A_n=a(2^n)+b$$now plug $$A_0,A_1$$ to find $a,b$
$$n=1 \to A_1=a(2^1)+b=5\\n=2 \to A_2=a(2^2)+b=13$$find $a,b$ $$a=4,b=-3\\A_n=4(2^n)-3$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I just had a question: How/why in the 3rd line do you get the +9 at the end? And then +12 +9 on the 4th?

Comment: I edit it again . $A_{n+1}=2A_{n}+3=2(2A_{n-1}+3)+3=4A_{n-1}+6+3$

Answer (score 4):

Call $B_n=A_n+3$. You have $$\begin{cases}B_{n+1}=2B_n\\ B_0=4\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is very nice, I would not have thought that it could be done so simply.

Comment: @AndresMejia It looks flashy the first time you see it, but it's actually a cheap way to mask the general method. I personally like best the one where you expand everything and use the sum of the geometric sequence.

Comment: I was going to write up a solution using generating functions, so it seems like this comes from that method, in that case. Is there any way to see this kind of relation efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

There is a general solution to such recurrence relations.

Suppose we have $x_n=ax_{n-1}+b$ with $a\neq0$ and $a_0$ given. If $b=0$ the solution is obvious.
If $b\neq 0$ we can solve immediatly for the constant solution $x_n=x$. This means $x=ax+b$ or $x=b/(1-a)$.
Next let $y_n=x_n-x$. Then $y_n=ay_{n-1}$, which means $y_n=a^ny_0$ (this is the case of $b=0$).
Substituting $x_n$ we find
$x_n=a^n(x_0-x)+x=a^n\left(x_0-b/(1-a)\right)+b/(1-a)$.

So in your example (for $A_0=0$) $A_n=2^n*3-3$
Or $A_n=2^n*4-3$ for $A_0=1$

Answer (score 0):

$$A_n = 2A_{n-1}+3$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A_n -2A_{n-1} = 3$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A_{n+1} -2A_{n} = 3$$
Thus, the characteristic equation of the homogeneous part is
$$c(\lambda)=\lambda - 2$$
Since its root is $\lambda^* = 2$, the homogeneous solution is
$$A_n = c\cdot 2^n$$
Because $A_0 = 1$ and $A_1 = 5$ we can conclude $ c = 4$:
$$A_0 = 4\cdot2^0-3$$
$$A_1 = 4\cdot2^1-3$$

Thus,
$$A_n =4\cdot 2^n-3$$